# Parsing the venues from foursquare /user/self/checkins data

Tags: php, json, foursquare

I'm trying to get the data of my users venues (the details about the venues from the users checkins information). 
I'm using the user access token to get the data. This is the code I'm using:

```
if($_GET['code']){
$authkey = file_get_contents("https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?   client_id=".$client_id."&client_secret=".$secret."&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=".$redirect."&code=".$_GET['code']);
$decoded_auth = json_decode($authkey,true);
$venueinfo = file_get_contents("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=$access_token&v=$version");
$decoded_venueinfo = json_decode($venueinfo, true);
foreach ($decoded_venueinfo->response->checkins->items->venue as $result){
    echo $result->name;
        echo $result->id;
        echo $result->location->address;
        echo $result->location->city;
        echo $result->location->country;    
    }
}
```

I get a blank page. I've tried to add "else" to the end of the first "if" with echo "error", and I got it displayed, so I guess my "if" statement condition is false.
I'm fairly new to PHP and I learn as I go. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The _GET['code'] refers to the "&code=" GET parameter in the URL of the request. This parameter will be present in requests that foursquare makes to your app to authenticate users. It sounds like you are manually making requests in order to test your app, in which case you will need to supply the code parameter in the URL.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have a parsing problem, I'm trying to display the venues that user checked in to. this is the code:  $decoded_venueinfo = json_decode($venueinfo, true);
foreach( $decoded_venueinfo->response->checkins-items-venue as $venue ){
      
        $name = $venue->name;
 $id =  $venue->id;                                                   echo "Venue name:$name, Id: $id"; }                                 It does not work. I get "Array" printed on the screen.